# Foreach Remove Files/Directories older than Mins/Days

Tags: powershell, loops

I am trying the delete some files that are older than X days from users’ directories, therefore I am using Loop to go through all the home drives and targeting one folder that I need to remove the sub files and sub directories older than specified days. In my script I am using the `(Get-Date).AddMinutes(-5)` so I can test it then I will change that to `(Get-Date).AddDays(-60)`.

I have complied the script that does what it supposed to be the outcome isn’t what I am hoping for so therefore it looks like I have the wrong code etc... I checked everywhere but couldn’t find the solution I was hoping for.

```
$mins = (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-5)
$path = "D:\Chrome\User Data" 

foreach ($i in $path) {
    Get-ChildItem -Path $i -Recurse |
    Where-Object { $_.CreationTime -lt $mins } | 
    $i = $_.FullName + "\*\js" + "\*" 
    Remove-Item $path -Recurse -WhatIf
}
```

I think I didn’t grasp the looping process, it looks like it’s going through all the particular directories the remove the files older than 5 minutes. Any help would be appreciated.

```
    $mins = (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-5)
$path = "D:\Chrome\User Data" 


Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.CreationTime -lt $mins} |ForEach-Object {
     $path = $_.FullName + "\*\js" + "\*" 
    Remove-Item $path -Recurse -WhatIf
    }
```

I have modified the scrip which does what it supposed to but still i cant get the files older then the 5 minutes.

Comment: Your `$path` value is a single directory. So when you use the syntax `foreach ($i in $path)`, it only iterates over one value, which is assigned to `$i` at the start of each loop iteration. Typically, `$path` in this case would be a collection. If you already know the one folder you need to delete from, then you don't need to loop it. It sounds like you need to loop through all of the home drives and then use `Get-ChildItem` on your built path, `<HOMEDRIVE>:\PATH`.

Comment: Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and tell us what the outcome is, and what you want it to be in a more clear manner. Your script as posted can't work. It should throw an error.

Comment: Sorry for asking the question wrong way. @AdminOfThings thanks for that, now its displaying the output as expected still i dont get the results i should have. 

```
$mins = (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-5)
$path = "D:\Chrome\User Data" 


Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.CreationTime -lt $mins} |ForEach-Object {
     $path = $_.FullName + "\*\js" + "\*" 
    Remove-Item $path -Recurse -WhatIf
    }
```

I cant seems to add it as a script code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's break down your requirements before rewriting your script:

1. Locate folders under `$path`
2. Locate items in each folder at `.\*\js\*`
3. Delete if created more than 60 days ago

With that in mind, let's go ahead and implement it:

```
$threshold = (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-5)
$path = "D:\Chrome\User Data" 

# Loop over each directory in $path
foreach ($folder in Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $path -Directory) {
  # Construct sub-folder path
  $subPath = Join-Path $folder.FullName "*\js\*"

  # Locate the files at *\js\*
  $files = Get-ChildItem $subPath -Recurse

  # Filter on Creation date
  $files = $files |Where-Object { $_.CreationTime -lt $threshold }

  # Remove files
  $files |Remove-Item -WhatIf
}
```

A dry run will tell you what will get removed, take out the `-WhatIf` switch at the end to actually remove them

Comment: Thank you for your kind help. This makes much for sense, and thank you for explaining this in great detail.

I have run the script and for some strange reasons its not picking up the correct path specified in $path variable. its picking up my current logged in user's path. 

**Get-ChildItem : Cannot find path 'C:\Users\pshell\rcrown' because it does not exist.**

Comment: Thats Great Mathias. This seems to be working as expected!

Comment: @metho I have the same problem - script is picking the wrong path when deleting. How did you solve this? Thanks in advance

Comment: @jose The error described in the comment above is already addressed in the answer. Are you running the code in my answer, or some other code?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I had code of my own, but the same problem with looping through the files. Your answer helped - it is working now. Thanks!